# Hierarchy with `list<self>` type

Tags: c++, collections

I want to establish a hierarchy, where at each level of the hierarchy, each type can contain a `list<its own type>`.  So `Node` (root of object class hierarchy) contains a `list<Node*>`, `SpecialNode : Node` contains a list of `SpecialNode`.  `SpecialNode` should not "accidentally" put new `SpecialNode` children into the `list<Node*>` in the base class, so the `list<>` are private.

I personally **hate** the concept of namehiding, because it is extremely prone to mistakes, uninitialized values, etc.  So here I have made it impossible (via `private`) for `SpecialNode` to "accidentally" insert into the `list<Node*>` instead of its own `list<SpecialNode*>`.

```
struct Node
{
private:
  list<Node*> children ;

protected:
  int v ;

public:
  Node( int iv ) : v(iv) { }

  virtual void print( const char* msg )
  {
    printf( "REGULAR CHILD %d in %s\n", v, msg ) ;
    for( Node *sn : Node::children )
      sn->print( "regular" ) ;

  }
} ;

struct SpecialNode : public Node
{
private:
  list<SpecialNode*> children ;

public:
  SpecialNode( int iv ) : Node(iv) { }
  void add( SpecialNode* child ) {
    children.push_back( child ) ;
  }

  void print( const char* msg )
  {
    printf( "SPECIAL CHILD %d in %s\n", v, msg ) ;
    for( SpecialNode *sn : children )
      sn->print( "special" ) ;

    //for( Node *sn : Node::children )
    //  sn->print( "regular" ) ;
  }

} ;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  SpecialNode *sn = new SpecialNode( 1 ) ;

  // SpecialNodes must contain SpecialNode children.
  sn->add( new SpecialNode( 2 ) ) ;
  //sn->children.push_back( new Node( 3 ) ) ; // fails b/c Node is too basic to fit in SpecialNode container.

  sn->print( "root" ) ;

}
```

Is this a good way to do this, or is there a better way?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? From your code it looks like you're only inheriting from `Node` so that you can have a 'level' to each node, is there a specific need to have a child with a parent each with a list of references to its own type (keep in mind that `std::list<SpecialNode>` will contain a `std::list<Node>` as well adding numerous levels of complexity)?

Comment: I'm trying to 1) Concrete each class' `list<self>` as its own type. 2) _Avoid name hiding errors and mistakes_

Comment: That's the mechanism you're trying to find, but why do you need it? Since a `SpecialNode*` can be stored in any `Node*`, such as the private `list<Node*>` if `Node` had an `add()`, but then unlike a `Node` it can't hold other `Node`s, this sounds like a violation of [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: your Node class has no add method in it at all, so you can never add any nodes to the base class. And you can only add SpecialNodes to the derived class. Perhaps what you would rather have are 2 separate classes with no relation or dependence on each other since you can't actually use these 2 together at all.

Answer (score 1):

You might prefer to not use polymorphism at all if you want to make sure that your types remain unique. Consider something more like:

```
class Node
{
private:
    list<Node*> children ;
    int v ;

public:
    Node( int iv ) : v(iv) { }

    void add( Node* child )
    {
        children.push_back( child );
    }

    void print( const char* msg )
    {
        printf( "REGULAR CHILD %d in %s\n", v, msg );
        for( Node *sn : Node::children )
        {
            sn->print( "regular" );
        }
    }
};

class SpecialNode // no inheritance
{
private:
    list<SpecialNode*> children;
    int v;

public:
    SpecialNode( int iv ) : v(iv) {}
    void add( SpecialNode* child )
    {
        children.push_back( child ) ;
    }

    void print( const char* msg )
    {
        printf( "SPECIAL CHILD %d in %s\n", v, msg ) ;
        for( SpecialNode *sn : children )
            sn->print( "special" ) ;
    }
};

class Composite // no inheritance
{
private:
    Node nodes;
    SpecialNode specialNodes;

public:
    Composite( int iv ) : nodes(iv), specialNodes(iv)
    void addSpecial( SpecialNode* child )
    {
        specialNodes.add( child ) ;
    }
    void add( Node * child)
    {
        nodes.add(child);
    }

    void print( const char* msg )
    {
        nodes.print(msg);
        specialNodes.print(msg);
    }
};
```